# Social network message board website security

Tags: php, sql, security, authentication

I have a script that contains functions from login in to posting status to friend request send and receive. Pretty much a social network script. Anyways i think my security is not up to date so if anyone can check my code out or review it live on the web: [`iphone.hostei.com`](http://iphone.hostei.com). email is `demo@demo.com` and password is `demo123`.

Please if anyone can review so my code is probably harder to hack and it functions well.

#### `profile.php`

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    //session_destroy();

    include_once('php/classes/db_config.php');
    include_once('php/classes/class.user.php');

    $user1 = new User($con);
    $is_loggedin = (isset($_SESSION['uid']))? true:false; 
    $is_uid = (isset($_GET['uid']) && !empty($_GET['uid']) && is_numeric($_GET['uid']))? true:false;
    // Set default uid
    $def_uid    =   ($is_uid == true)? $_GET['uid']: $_SESSION['uid'];
    // User valid check
    $user_valid =   ($is_uid == true)? $user1->check_user($def_uid):1;

    $name_id = $_SESSION['user']['uid'];
    $name = $_SESSION['user']['uname'];
    $fullname = $_SESSION['user']['fullname'];
    $bio = $_SESSION['user']['bio'];

    $time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

    if(isset($_POST['logout'])) {
        session_destroy();
        header('Location: index.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['area_sub'])){
        if(empty($_POST['area'])){
            echo "<script>alert('Empty area field.')</script>";
        }else{
            if($_GET['uid'] == ''){
                $user1 -> post($_SESSION['uid'], $_SESSION['uid'], $name, $_POST['area'], $time);
            }else if($_GET['uid'] == 0){
            }else{
                $user1 -> post($_SESSION['uid'], $_GET['uid'], $name, $_POST['area'], $time);
            }
        }
    }
    if($is_loggedin){
        $check = $con -> Fetch("SELECT * FROM follow_req WHERE user_two_req=".$_SESSION['uid']."");
    }

?>

    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Only Simple Albanian Social Network, with no ads</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/profile.css"/>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>
    <?php if($is_loggedin !== true) { 
            include_once 'php/common/head.php'; ?>
    <?php }?>

    <?php
    // If there is a propper UID available
    if(($is_loggedin == true) || ($is_uid == true)) { ?>

    <?php if ($is_loggedin == true){ ?>

    <div id="menu">
        <div id="menu_wrapper">
            <div id="left_menu">

            </div>
            <div id="right_menu">
                <div id='drop-zone'><?php
                    if($check == 0){
                        echo "<h4 class='request'>0</h4>";
                    }else{ 
                        echo "<a href='#' class='request_more'>".count($check)."</a>";
                    }   
                ?></div>
                <form action='' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='logout' value='true' />
                    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Logout' id='btn'>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>

    <div id="profile_wrapper">

        <div class="wrapper">

            <div id="profile">  

            <?php

            // If user is valid
            if($user_valid == 1) {
                // User is logged in user
                if($def_uid == $_SESSION['uid']) {
                    include_once 'php/classes/profile_func.php';
                } 
                include_once 'php/classes/user_info.php';

            }else{?>
                <h2>No Such User Exists</h2>
                <h3>Please select a different user or <a href='index.php'>Login</a></h3>
                <?php if($is_loggedin == true){ ?>
                        <h3>Go Back to <a href="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $name_id;?>">My Profile</a></h3>
                    <?php
                }
            } ?>

<?php }else{?>
        <h1>Invalid User</h1>
        <h3>You must be <a href="index.php">Logged IN</a> to see your profile OR you must select a profile (uid) to view.</h3>
<?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php if($is_loggedin != true){ ?>
    <div id="footer">
        <h4>Per momentin vetem njerezit qe do perzgjidhen do kene akses.</h4>
        <a href="#">
            <div id="button">Kerkese Hyerje</div>
        </a>
        </div>
<?php } ?>

<script>
function LookUp(IdElem,URL){
        $("#drop-zone").html('<div class="loader"></div>');
        $.ajax({
                url: URL,
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                        $("#drop-zone").html(result);
                    }
            });
}
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("a.request_more").click(function(){
            LookUp(this,'requests.php');
        });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

#### `profile_funct.php`

```
    <?php $user1->profile_photo(); ?>               
<div id="friends">
<?php 
    echo "
        <h2 class='u_name'><a href=profile.php?uid=".$name_id.">@".$name."</a></h2>
        <br/>
        <p>".$fullname."</p>
    ";

    $MyFollows  =   $con->Fetch("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE (user_one='$def_uid') OR (user_two='$def_uid')");
    $count_posts = $con->Fetch("SELECT * FROM post WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['uid']." ");
    echo  "<p>Posts ".$cnt = ($count_posts !== 0)? '<a href="posts.php" class="posts_all">'. count($count_posts) .'</a>' : 0;"";
    echo " - Friends: ".$following = ($MyFollows !== 0)? '<a class="frnd_a" href="friends.php">'. count($MyFollows) .'</a></p>' : 0;"";
?>
</div>
<div id="post_wrapper">
    <p>Update Status</p>
    <div id='post_form'>
        <form action='' method='POST'>
            <textarea id='area' name='area'></textarea>
            <input type='submit' name='area_sub' id='sub_btn' value='Update'/>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
<?php 
if($_GET['uid'] == 0){
    $user1 -> getResults();
}else{
    $user1 -> getResults();
}?>
```

#### `user_info.php`

```
  <?php if($def_uid != $_SESSION['uid']) {
    $info = $con->Fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid='$def_uid'"); ?>
    <h1>User Profile: <?php echo $info[0]['fullname']; ?></h1>
    <?php
    $action = ($user1->check_req($_SESSION['uid'], $def_uid))? true : false;
    $friends = ($user1->check_friends($_SESSION['uid'], $def_uid))? true: false;
    $c = ($user1->checking($def_uid, $_SESSION['uid']))? true: false;

    $post = $con->Fetch("SELECT * FROM `post` WHERE rec_id=".$_GET['uid']."");
    ?>

<?php
    if($friends == true){
        echo "Welcome to ", $info[0]['uname'],"'s wall";

        if($is_loggedin == true){
            echo "<br/>Go Back to <a href='profile.php?uid=".$_SESSION['user']['uid']."'>My Profile</a><br/>";
        }

        ?>
        <br/>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <textarea id='area' name='area' placeholder="Say something nice <?php echo $name;?>"></textarea>
            <input type='submit' name='area_sub' value='Go'/>
        </form>
        <br/>
        <?php

        if($_GET['uid'] == $post[0]['rec_id']){
            echo "<br/>".$user1 -> getResults();
        }
        echo "<br/><a href='actions.php?action=unfriend&uid=".$def_uid."'/>Unfriend</a><br/>";

    }else{

        if($is_loggedin == true){
?>
            <a href="actions.php?action=
            <?php if($action == true){ $un = "cancel";echo $un;}else{echo "send";}?>&uid=
            <?php echo $def_uid; ?>">
            <?php if($c == true){
                    echo"<a href='actions.php?action=accept&uid=".$def_uid."'>ADD</a><br/>"; 
                    echo "<a href='actions.php?action=ignore&uid=".$def_uid."'>Ignore</a>";
                }else if($action == true){
                    echo $un;
                }else{
                    echo "send";
                }?>
            </a>

            <br/>Back to my <a href="profile.php?uid=<?php echo $_SESSION['user']['uid']; ?>">Profile</a>

            <?php

        }else{
            echo "Not Logged In. Log in <a href='index.php'>Here</a>";
        }

    }
}
?>
```

`class.user.php`

```
    <?php
class User
    {
        public  $db;
        public  $error;

        public function __construct($con){
                $this->db = $con;
        }

        /*** for login process ***/
        public function check_login($username='', $password=''){
                // Validate that your email is a real one
                if(filter_var($username,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) !== false) {
                        $password   =   md5($password);
                        $sql        =   "SELECT uid from users WHERE (uemail='$username' or uname='$username') and upass = '$password'";
                        $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);

                            if ($result !== 0) {
                                    // this login var will use for the session thing
                                    $_SESSION['emailusername']  =   $result[0]['uemail'];
                                    $_SESSION['uid']            =   $result[0]['uid'];
                                    $_SESSION['user']           =   $this->get_fullname($result[0]['uid'],0);
                                    $_SESSION['login']          =   true;
                                }
                            else
                                $this->error['Invalid Account'] = '<h3 id="error">Invalid Username or Password</h3>';
                    }
                else
                    $this->error['Email'] = '<h3 id="error">Invalid Email Address</h3>';

                return  (!isset($_SESSION['emailusername']))? false:true;
            }

        /*** for showing the username or fullname ***/
        public function get_fullname($uid, $write = 1){

                // --> You can prepare, bind, and execute your values here replacing what you have now....<--

                $sql                =   "SELECT * FROM users WHERE uid = '$uid'";
                $user_data          =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);

                if($user_data !== 0) {
                        $user['uname']      =   $user_data[0]['uname'];
                        $user['fullname']   =   $user_data[0]['fullname'];
                        $user['uemail']     =   $user_data[0]['uemail'];
                        $user['uid']        =   $user_data[0]['uid'];
                        $user['bio']        =   $user_data[0]['bio'];

                        // This gives the option of returning an array (setting session array) or echoing
                        if($write == 1)
                            echo implode("<br />",$user);
                        else
                            return $user;
                    }
            }

        public function check_user($uid)
            {
                $sql        =   "SELECT * from users WHERE uid= $uid ";
                $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);
                $count_row  =   ($result !== 0)? count($result): 0;

                return $count_row;
            }

        /*** starting the session ***/
        public function get_session()
            {
                return $_SESSION['login'];
            }

        public function user_logout()
            {
                $_SESSION['login'] = FALSE;
                session_destroy();
            }
        public function check_req($is_uid, $def_uid){
            $sql        =   "SELECT * from follow_req WHERE user_one_req = '$is_uid' AND user_two_req = '$def_uid'";
            $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);
            $count_row  =   ($result !== 0)? count($result): 0;
            return $count_row;
        }
        public function insert($is_uid, $def_uid){
            $sql        =   "INSERT INTO follow_req (user_one_req, user_two_req) VALUES (:user_one_req, :user_two_req)";
            $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $q -> execute(array(':user_one_req'=>$is_uid, ':user_two_req'=>$def_uid));

            return $q;
        }
        public function delete($is_uid, $def_uid){
            $sql        =   "DELETE FROM follow_req WHERE user_one_req = :user_one_req AND user_two_req = :user_two_req";
            $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $q -> execute(array(':user_one_req'=>$is_uid, ':user_two_req'=>$def_uid));
            return $q;
        }
        public function checkimg($img_id){
            $sql        =   "SELECT * from users WHERE img_id = '$img_id'";
            $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);
            $count_row  =   ($result !== 0)? count($result): 0;
            return $count_row;
        }
        public function img($img_id, $part){
            $sql        =   "UPDATE users SET img_id='$img_id', image='$part' WHERE uid=".$_SESSION['uid']."";
            $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $q -> execute(array(':img_id'=>$img_id, ':image'=>$part));
            return $q;
        }
        public function check_friends($is_uid, $def_uid){
            $sql        =   "SELECT * from follow WHERE (user_one = '$is_uid' AND user_two = '$def_uid') OR (user_one = '$def_uid' AND user_two = '$is_uid')";
            $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);
            $count_row  =   ($result !== 0)? count($result): 0;
            return $count_row;
        }
        public function del_friends($is_uid, $def_uid){
            $sql        =   "DELETE FROM follow WHERE (user_one = :user_one AND user_two = :user_two) OR (user_one = :user_two AND user_two = :user_one)";
            $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $q -> execute(array(':user_one'=>$is_uid, ':user_two'=>$def_uid));
            return $q;
        }
        public function checking($def_uid, $is_uid){
            $sql        =   "SELECT * from follow_req WHERE user_one_req = '$def_uid' AND user_two_req = '$is_uid'";
            $result     =   $this->db->Fetch($sql);
            $count_row  =   ($result !== 0)? count($result): 0;
            return $count_row;
        }
        public function accept_req($def_uid, $is_uid){
            $sql        =   "INSERT INTO follow ( user_one, user_two) VALUES ( :user_one, :user_two)";
            $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $q -> execute(array(':user_one'=>$def_uid, ':user_two'=>$is_uid));
            return $q;
        }
        public function delete_req($def_uid, $is_uid){
            $sql        =   "DELETE FROM follow_req WHERE user_one_req = :user_one_req AND user_two_req = :user_two_req";
            $q = $this->db->prepare($sql);
            $q -> execute(array(':user_one_req'=>$def_uid, ':user_two_req'=>$is_uid));
            return $q;
        }
        public function post($a_id='', $r_id='', $name, $area='', $time){
            $sql = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO post (user_id, rec_id, user, area, time) VALUES ( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
            $sql -> bindParam(1, $a_id);
            $sql -> bindParam(2, $r_id);
            $sql -> bindParam(3, $name);
            $sql -> bindParam(4, $area);
            $sql -> bindParam(5, $time);
            $sql -> execute();
        }
        public function profile_photo(){
            $get_name = $this->db->Fetch ("SELECT * FROM users WHERE img_id=". $_SESSION['uid']."");            
            if($get_name[0]['img_id'] == $_SESSION['uid']){
                echo "<img id='profile_img' src='test/upload/".$_SESSION['uid']."_".$get_name[0]['image']."'/>";
            }else{  
                echo "<img id='profile_img' src='classversiondontdelete/images/default/profile_icon.gif'/>";
                //echo "<img src='test/upload/".$_SESSION['uid']."_".$get_name[0]['image']."'/>";
            }
        }
        public function getResults(){
            if($_GET['uid'] == ''){
                $result = $this->db->Fetch("SELECT * FROM post WHERE rec_id = ".$_SESSION['uid']." ");
            }else if($_GET['uid'] == 0){
                $result = $this->db->Fetch("SELECT * FROM post WHERE rec_id = ".$_SESSION['uid']." ");
            }else{
                if(is_numeric($_GET['uid']))
                    $result = $this->db->Fetch("SELECT * FROM post WHERE rec_id = '".$_GET['uid']."'");
            }
            if(is_array($result)){
                foreach ($result as $row) {
                    ?><div id="post"><?php
                    $get_name = $this->db->Fetch("SELECT * FROM users WHERE img_id = ".$row['user_id']."");
                    if($get_name[0]['img_id'] != 0){
                        echo "<img id='post_img' src='test/upload/".$row['user_id']."_".$get_name[0]['image']."'/>";
                    }else{  
                        echo "<img id='post_img' src='classversiondontdelete/images/default/profile_icon.gif'/>";
                    }
                    echo "
                        <h3 id='text'>".$row['area']. "</h3>
                    ";
                    ?></div><?php
                }
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment on security as I haven't had time to go through and understand the code,
but I have written comments in regards to coding style, search for // ### to see my comments.

I will have another look later if I get time

```
<?php
session_start();
//session_destroy();

include_once('php/classes/db_config.php');
include_once('php/classes/class.user.php');

$user1 = new User($con);

// ### no point using tenary operator here given isset returns a boolean anyway
// $is_loggedin = (isset($_SESSION['uid']))? true:false;
$is_loggedin = (isset($_SESSION['uid']));

// ### you don't need to test isset and empty, empty takes care of both
// $is_uid = (isset($_GET['uid']) && !empty($_GET['uid']) && is_numeric($_GET['uid']))? true:false;
$is_uid = (!empty($_GET['uid']) && is_numeric($_GET['uid']));

// Set default uid
// ## this can also be shortened although not essential
// $def_uid    =   ($is_uid == true)? $_GET['uid']: $_SESSION['uid'];
$def_uid = ($is_uid) ? $_GET['uid'] : $_SESSION['uid'];

// ### what if $_SESSION['uid'] is not set?

// User valid check
// ### what does 1 mean, perhaps define a constant or use true/false instead
$user_valid = ($is_uid == true) ? $user1->check_user($def_uid) : 1;

// ## if $_SESSION['user'] doesn't exist these assignments will generate warnings
$name_id = $_SESSION['user']['uid'];
$name = $_SESSION['user']['uname'];
$fullname = $_SESSION['user']['fullname'];
$bio = $_SESSION['user']['bio'];

$time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

if (isset($_POST['logout'])) {
    session_destroy();
    header('Location: index.php');
    // ### need to exit after header or your script keeps executing
    exit;
}

if (isset($_POST['area_sub'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['area'])) {
        echo "<script>alert('Empty area field.')</script>";
    } else {

        // ### i would simplify this block of code
//        if ($_GET['uid'] == '') {
//            $user1->post($_SESSION['uid'], $_SESSION['uid'], $name, $_POST['area'], $time);
//        } else if ($_GET['uid'] == 0) {
//            // ### what is the point of this condition?
//        } else {
//            $user1->post($_SESSION['uid'], $_GET['uid'], $name, $_POST['area'], $time);
//        }

        $uid = $_GET['uid']; // assuming it is set
        if ($uid == '') {
            $uid = $_SESSION['uid']; // assuming it is set
        }

        $user1->post($_SESSION['uid'], $uid, $name, $_POST['area'], $time);
    }
}
if ($is_loggedin) {
    // ### you used prepared statements elsewhere, why not here?
    $check = $con->Fetch("SELECT * FROM follow_req WHERE user_two_req=" . $_SESSION['uid'] . "");
}

?>
```

Comment: Hello. This is much better?                `if($is_loggedin){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM follow_req WHERE user_two_req= :user_two_req";
  $query = $con->prepare($sql);
  $query->execute(array( ':user_two_req' => $name_id));
 }`

Answer (score 0):

You dont prepare  your SELECT and UPDATE statements, and dont use md5; http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash

You should atleast add "salt" to your passwords; http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.salt